# Configuring NSight (Eclipse) and ld

Tags: eclipse, cuda, ld, nsight

I'm trying to build a project in nsight using the cufft.so library, but the linker (ld) can't find the library file, and I'm stumped.

The library is installed as /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so

In the project properties I have gone to "General->Paths and Symbols->Libraries" tab and added /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so, and for good measure went to the Libraries Paths tab and added /usr/local/cuda/lib64

The exact error is

```
Finished building: ../main.cu

Building target: cufftTest2
Invoking: NVCC Linker
/usr/local/cuda-5.5/bin/nvcc --cudart static -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -link -o  "cufftTest2"  ./main.o   -l/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cufftTest2] Error 1
```

and the environment paths are configured as:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda/lib64:
echo $PATH
/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/cuda/man:
```

I'm sure I've done something dumb, but I have no idea why ld can't find /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Solution, with many thanks to Robert Crovella: Library Paths is empty, Library is just "cufft"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `cufft` as the library, so that it shows up as `-lcufft` in the actual linker command line.

The gcc linker used by nvcc for host code compilation and linking expects the libraries to be indicated like this:

Library:

```
/path/to/library/libmystuff.so
```

Linker switches:

```
-L/path/to/library/
-lmystuff
```

(notice that the `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix are dropped)